# How can I display this array in the marquee tag?

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

How can I display this array in the `<marquee>` tag?
I can't display these messages in the HTML

Can I get some help in this case?

```js
var messages = [
  { name: "Asi", context: "Bla Bla", picture: "asi.jpg" },
  { name: "Lior", context: "Bla Bla", picture: "lior.jpg" },
];

function showMessages() {
  let messageBox = document.getElementById("messagesBox");
  const allTheMessage = messages.map((m) => (
    <div>
      {m.name}
      <br />
      {m.context}
      <br />
      {m.picture}
      <br />
    </div>
  ));

  messageBox.innerHTML = allTheMessage.toString();
}

showMessages();
```

```html
<marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down">
    <h1 id="messagesBox"></h1>
</marquee>
```

Comment: [marquee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) is obsolete

Comment: Marquee, wow, welcome to the bleeding edge of 1999. You'll love the next 21 years, though you might want to avoid 2020, it's a bit of a sh*t storm. :D

Answer (score 0):

You have not valid JS in map callback. [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) takes

> A DOMString containing the HTML serialization of the element's descendants

so you need to collect the [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var messages = [
    { name: "Asi", context: "Bla Bla", picture: "asi.jpg" },
    { name: "Lior", context: "Bla Bla", picture: "lior.jpg" },
];

function showMessages() {
    let messageBox = document.getElementById("messagesBox");
    const allTheMessage = messages.map(m => `<div>${m.name}<br />${m.context}<br />${m.picture}<br /></div>`);
    messageBox.innerHTML = allTheMessage.join('');
}

showMessages();
```

```html
<marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down">
    <h1 id="messagesBox"></h1>
</marquee>
```

Comment: An explanation of what you changed and/ or what was wrong would be good